# How can i change this to a hyper link? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i have this command that i made to invite my bot to other servers, it sends an embed of the bots invite and the support server. I want to change the actual links to hyper links, like clickable messages,
example: "Invite Me!" and it would be blue and you'd be able to click on it to go to the link. here is the command

```
    @commands.cooldown(rate=1, per=10.5, type=commands.BucketType.user)
    @commands.command(aliases=['joinme', 'botinvite', 'kek'])
    async def invite(self, ctx):
        """ Invite me to your server """
        try:
            await ctx.message.delete()
        except:
            pass

        embed = discord.Embed(color=ctx.author.color, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)

        embed.set_author(
        name=ctx.bot.user.name, icon_url=ctx.bot.user.avatar_url_as(static_format="png")
        )
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.bot.user.avatar_url_as(static_format="png"))
        embed.add_field(
            name="Bot Invite",
            value="https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=723726581864071178&permissions=1576533239&scope=bot")

        embed.add_field(
            name=f"Support Server",
            value="https://discord.gg/cNRNeaX")

        embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

        try:
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        except Exception as err:
            await ctx.send(err)
```

Comment: URL Markdown `[Click here] (http://www.google.com)` can not be used in Titles, as a note.  So for instance, you can't do `embed.add_field(name="[bot invite] (url here)")` because that is a title but you **can** do it here `embed.add_field(name="Bot Invite", value="[Click Here] (URL HERE)")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an embed you should be able to use the markdown.

```
Click [here] (discord.gg/CODE)to join my awesome server!
```